# Read data from array loaded with data within JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to load an JSON file into an array and then read from the array but the alert is not showing any data.

**JSON file: data.json**

```
[
{"Name":"name1", "Occupation":"occ1"},
{"Name":"name2", "Occupation":"occ2"},
{"Name":"name3", "Occupation":"occ3"},
{"Name":"name4", "Occupation":"occ4"},
{"Name":"name5", "Occupation":"occ5"}
]
```

**JQuery code**

```
function getJsonData() {
    var arrJson = [];

    $.getJSON("data.json", function( data){
      arrJson = data;
    });
    return arrJson;     
};  

$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [];
    data = getJsonData();
    //console.log(data);

    $.each(data, function(i, value){
        alert('index: ' + i + ',value: ' + value);
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

`getJsonData();` Is a asynchronous function, meaning it returns an answer in a different timeline as the rest of the script.

What you need to do is implement a `callback`

Otherwise, moving the foreach loop inside the async function will also do the trick:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function( data){
  arrJson = data;
  $.each(data, function(i, value){
        alert('index: ' + i + ',value: ' + value);
   });

});
```

Comment: Hi Skarlinski, I am new to jquery and I don't know how to implement this callback.  Do you have an example with a callback using getJSON that you can share?